# Return local variable to const ref from lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, const-reference

```
const TBigType& a = [](){
    TBigType result;
    // ...
    return result;
}();

use(a); // by const ref
```

Is it ok to capture result in const ref like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your lambda returns a prvalue, so the call expression is a temporary object, whose lifetime is extended because it is bound to a reference.

The situation is entirely analogous to the following, simpler example:

```
int f() { return 12; }

const int& a = f();
```

Here `a` is bound to a temporary object of type `int` and value `12`.

If you do not specify the return type of a lambda, the return type is always either `void` or an object type. If you want your lambda to return an lvalue or xvalue, you will explicitly need to specify the return type, e.g. as `-> int&`, `-> auto&`, `-> decltype(auto)`, etc.

Comment: But it would be better to give `TBigType` a move constructor if possible.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Meh. It'll be copy-elided anyway.

Comment: I prefer to be entirely certain. Pre-C++17, that's a move constructor.